# Valgrind warning write and read errors

Tags: c, string, valgrind

I'm having **write/read** problems with **valgrind** and I don't understand why. The errors occurs on the same code block all time, changing only the memory address. The code block is:

```
void stringModifier(char *string) {
    char *sourceString = string;
    char *destinyString = sourceString;

    while(*string != '\0') {
            *string = tolower(*string);

            if(*string != ' ') { *destinyString++ = *string; }

            string++;
    }

    *destinyString = '\0';
}

int qsortComparison(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(char *)a - *(char *)b);
}

void qsortString(char *string, char *tempString) {
    strcpy(tempString, string);
    stringModifier(tempString);
    qsort(tempString, strlen(tempString), sizeof(char), qsortComparison);
}

void outputReader(char *string1, char *string2) {
    char *tempString1 = (char *) malloc (strlen(string1) * sizeof(char));
    char *tempString2 = (char *) malloc (strlen(string2) * sizeof(char));

    qsortString(string1, tempString1);
    qsortString(string2, tempString2);

    if(!strcmp(tempString1, tempString2)) { printf("V\n", string1, string2); }
    else { printf("F\n"); }
}
```

Every time I use **outputReader** and call **qsortString**, **valgrind** warn a **write** error at **strcpy** and after that warn a **read** error at **stringModifier**, occurring on the same memory address.

Comment: Where is sourcestring coming from?

Comment: sourceString is on stringModifier scope and take information for tempString parameter of qsortString. But I think that the really problem was on strcpy..

Comment: Have you allocated space for tempstring  (alloc or malloc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the path of one of the invocations in question.

1. `char *tempString1 = (char *) malloc (strlen(string1) * sizeof(char));` : This allocates a string buffer that is the number of characters in `string1` **NOT including the `0`-terminator**, Space for the terminator is required if you want to store a *complete* copy of the string, but you don't allocate it.
2. `qsortString(string1, tempString1);` : Now we pass both the source string buffer *and* the newly allocated one-char-too-short buffer to this function.
3. In `qsortString()`, you then `strcpy(tempString, string);` : This will write one additional char (the terminator) to memory you don't own. This is therefore **undefined behavior**.

Valrind is right. You're writing (then reading) memory you don't own. The allocation should include space for a `0`-terminator. such as: `malloc ((strlen(string1)+1) * sizeof(char));` Another option, though not part of the C-standard, is to use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html), which would handle both allocation *and* copying for you correctly. How you choose to approach the solution I leave to you.

Side Note: [Don't cast `malloc()` return values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: I understand now what happened. I forgot the 0-terminator of the copy operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to alloc strlen+1 to account for null terminator of string.

```
void outputReader(char *string1, char *string2) {
    char *tempString1 = (char *) malloc ((strlen(string1)+1) * sizeof(char));
    char *tempString2 = (char *) malloc ((strlen(string2)+1) * sizeof(char));
```